# How to split audio or write demuxer filter in directshow?

Tags: c++, filter, directshow

I need to split a PCM audio stream with up to 16 channels into several stereo streams.
As I haven't found anything capable of doing that, I'm trying to write my first directshow filter.

Anything capable of splitting the audio would be very welcomed but I'm assuming that I must do it so there's what I've done:

At first, I tried to create a filter based on ITransformFilter. However, it seems that it's made thinking of filters with only one input pin and one output pin. As I need several output pins, I disregarded it, however perhaps it can be adapted more easily than I thought, so any advice is highly appreciated.

Then, I begin basing on IBaseFilter. I managed to do something. I create the necessary output pins when the input pin gets connected, and destroy them when the input gets disconnected. However, when I connect any output pin to an ACM Wrapper (just to test it), the input tries to reconnect, destroying all my output pins.
I tried to just not destroy them, but then I checked the media type of my input pin and it had changed to a stereo stream. I'm not calling QueryAccept from my code.

How could I avoid the reconnection, or what's the right way to do a demuxer filter?

**Edit 2010-07-09:**
I've come back to ITransformFilter, but I'm creating the necessary pins. However I've encountered the same problem as with IBaseFilter: When I connect my output pin to an ACM Wrapper, the input pins changes its mediatype to 2 channels.
Not sure how to proceed now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the DMOSample in the *Windows Server 2003 R2 Platform SDK*. It is also included in older directx sdk's, but not in newer windows sdk's. You can locate it in Samples\Multimedia\DirectShow\DMO\DMOSample. [Here](http://doc.51windows.net/Directx9_SDK/?url=/Directx9_SDK/htm/dmosample.htm) is the documentation of this sample.

I have seen someone create a filter based on this which had a stereo input and two mono outputs. Unfortunately I cannot post the sourcecode.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I need. It seems that the output pins must be declared in advance. Being able to create them in real time would be nice, as I don't know how much channels I've got until the input is connected. Will pick your answer if nobody answers in one day or two, tho.

Comment: You can create 16 output pins and only use the pins you need.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that but the "up to 16" could change in the future. When it's "up to 32", what, 32 pins? And then, when someone has a 128 channel stream? Doesn't seem very likely, but again 15 years ago I would have not believed that you could have 64 gb of data in 1 square cm, so...
My solution has finally been to write a standard transform filter and connect several instances of it through an Inf Tee, then configuring each one to pick the channels I want. 
Thank you very much.